# How resolve conflict with maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

i have pom file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2d2abdc47d868250e8f47d74bdd643c2

i build with command: `clean compile assembly:single`

but i get warning:

> [WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for
>   com.xxx.backtesting:client:jar should not point at files within the
>   project directory,
>   ${project.basedir}/lib/client-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar will be
>   unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 18, column 25

and this library doesnt exist in jar file:

---

When i run my jar file, i got:

```
java -jar backtestingCandlesDownloader-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar 1440672480000 1441025280000 60000
task: startDate = 1440672480000, endDate = 1441025280000, period = 60000
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/xxx/backtesting/client/model/Server
    at com.xxx.backtestingCandlesDownloader.Main.main(Main.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxx.backtesting.client.model.Server
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

i dont know how include client-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar in jar file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your warning is referring to line 16 and 18 of your POM:

```
<scope>system</scope>
...
<systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/client-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar</systemPath>
```

These lines identify a `systemPath` for a library and `scope` lets Maven know it is provided by the system instead of within the project [1].

Your best approach would be to include it in your local Maven Repository by installing it as part of your build. This will install the client jar file as a maven artifact in your local Maven repository during the clean phase making it available to dependency projects. Installing as part of the lifecycle ensures the artifact is available automatically for all future developers/builds.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Installs new artifact in the local repository -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install-artifact</id>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <file>${project.basedir}/lib/client-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar</file>
                        <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                        <groupId>com.xxx.backtesting</groupId>
                        <artifactId>client</artifactId>
                        <version>0.1</version>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                        <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Once installed, you simply reference it as a dependency as you would any other Maven dependency:

```
<dependencies>
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xxx.backtesting</groupId>
        <artifactId>client</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
    </dependency>
...
</depencencies>
```

Alternatively, you could install the artifact via command line, but would have to fully qualify the location of your jar file [2]. After installing using the command line method, you would be able to use the library as you would any other dependency in Maven:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/path/to/lib/client-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar -DgroupId=com.xxx.backtesting -DartifactId=client -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

1. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope
2. https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have lib/client-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar in your project directory,then replace ${project.basedir} with ${pom.basedir}